# Is there a way that I can fade from one screen to another with AngularJS and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I change from one state to another some of the transitions seem very fast.  Is there a simple way that I can make my screen transition with a fade out and fade in. I'm not thinking just even a 0.2 second out and 0.2 second in would be okay.

I would appreciate some suggestions on where to start looking and how I could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Angular ui-router provides some events while changing states such as :

- $stateChangeStart
- $stateChangeSuccess etc.

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',

```
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
    // a 'transition prevented' error
});
```

or

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

I would recommend you to use `'$stateChangeSuccess'` and add a $timeout or any other animation to fade away from one state to another.

For more you can refer to the following link :
[State Change events in angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) on the [UI-Router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/):

[How to: Animate ui-view with ng-animate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate)

When you include the `angular-animate` javascript asset, UI-Router automaticly adds `ng-enter`, `ng-enter-active`, `ng-leave` and `ng-leave-active` classes to the state changing UI-view. You can use those to attach your own CSS animations:

CSS:

```
[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's an example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nx2enw?p=preview